# Asignarle un valor a un input con js

Tags: javascript, php, html, input

Quiero asignarle un valor a un input por medio de `input.value` pero el input aparece vacio y no se envia nada en el formulario, aunque en el `console.log` muestra el valor que se le debe asignar

Boton para asignarle el valor al input

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="asignarUsuario(<?php echo $row['usu_id'] ?>, '<?php echo $nombre ?>')">
```

Funcion para asignar el valor

```
var nombre = document.getElementById("nombreUsuario");
var id = document.getElementById("idUsuario");
function asignarUsuario(idUsuario, nombreUsuario) {
  id.value = idUsuario
  nombre.innerHTML = nombreUsuario;
  console.log(id);
  console.log(id.value);

};
```

Input a asignarle el valor

```
<input type="text" name="idUsuario" id="idUsuario" value="">
```

Todo en un snippet de ejemplo:

```js
var nombre = document.getElementById("nombreUsuario");
var id = document.getElementById("idUsuario");
function asignarUsuario(idUsuario, nombreUsuario) {
  id.value = idUsuario
  nombre.innerHTML = nombreUsuario;
  console.log(id);
  console.log(id.value);

};
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="asignarUsuario(14, 'pedro')">Asignar usuario</button>

<input type="text" name="idUsuario" id="idUsuario" value="">
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el input que te aparece vacío? El de `idUsuario` o el de `nombreUsuario`? ¿O es que `nombreUsuario` no es un input? No queda claro, porque pones un código mínimo. Y a todo eso... cuando pones `<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="asignarUsuario(<?php echo $row['usu_id'] ?>, '<?php echo $nombre ?>')">`... ¿`$row` ya contiene los valores correctos de esa fila?

Comment: Acabo de agregar un snippet de ejemplo con tu código en la pregunta. Aparte de que no cierras el botón, parece funcionar correctamente.

Comment: @VFG Hola, es `idUsuario`. `nombreUsuario` no es de un input solo que puse la funcion entera. Y si `$row` tiene los valores

Comment: @masterguru El boton si esta cerrado solo que copie mal. Pero me parece extraño por que como digo el valor del input se muestra vacio

Comment: El valor del input se muestra vacio hasta que pulsas el botón. Compruébalo ejecutando el snippet que acabo de arreglar cerrando el botón.

Comment: Vale, es un efecto óptico... realmente no cambia el valor del atributo **value=**.  Para ello prueba con esto: `id.setAttribute("value",idUsuario)`

Comment: @masterguru es igual, en la consola muestra como si tuviese el valor pero en relidad no cambia. Consola `<input id="idUsuario" type="hidden" value="234" name="idUsuario">`. Inspector `<input id="idUsuario" type="hidden" value="" name="idUsuario">`

Comment: hidden?  El input de la pregunta no tiene ese atributo... A ver si vas a tener dos input con el mismo **id** y tan solo cambia el primero de ellos

Comment: Yo te pediría que pongas el código relevante en un JSFiddle, codesandbox o similar donde se pueda probar lo que comentas tal y como lo tienes. Si no, se hace difícil

Comment: @VFG perdon soy, nuevo en esto no se que es JSFiddle y demas

Comment: @masterguru @VFG Gracias por ayudarme, ya encontre el problema, aunque no se muy bien el porque psaba esto, ni porque mostraba el input como hidden. Cambie el nobre de la id del `input` y funciono correctamente